# How do I output a .txt file within a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, escaping

I am attempting to build a C program using a Makefile but unfortunately, I am having errors when I attempt to call a defined variable even after escaping it and trying other escape techniques.

The text file greetings-file.txt contains the string `"Goodnight Moon!\n"`

Here's my code:

```
F= greetings-file.txt
M= Makefile-hello

# complete the makefile as instructed in the quiz2.txt file # you will need to add dependencies after the target(s) 
# as well as actions in the recipes

program: hello
    @echo run hello
    ./hello

hello.c:
    @echo make hello.c based on $F and $M
    @echo "#include<stdio.h>" > hello.c
    @echo "int main(){printf(\"`cat $F`\");}" >> hello.c

hello: hello.c
    @echo compile hello.c
    cc -o hello hello.c

clean:
    @echo cleanup hello
    -rm hello hello.c
```

This is my error:

```
compile hello.c
cc -o hello hello.c
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:2:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Goodnight’
 int main(){printf(""Goodnight Moon!
                     ^~~~~~~~~
hello.c:2:19: warning: zero-length gnu_printf format string [-Wformat-zero-length]
 int main(){printf(""Goodnight Moon!
                   ^~
Makefile-hello:27: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the *text* from your terminal, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Images are not searchable. Please post the error message as text

Comment: Also, it says clearly that you're missing a `"` character...

Comment: Sorry for the mishap. I included the `"` character and I still got errors

Comment: From your updated error log, it seems you have added " twice. Try removing the double quotation marks from `\"cat $F\"` line since `"Goodnight Moon!\n"` already has them.

Comment: @Alaiko I removed the quotation marks and I got this error `compile hello.c
cc -o hello hello.c
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile-hello:27: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 1`

Comment: That error means you do not have a main function defined. Maybe check the hello.c file and see its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler message shows you the first part of the statement that failed, and even helpfully points out the exact location of the error:

> ```
>  int main(){printf(""Goodnight Moon!
>                      ^~~~~~~~~
> ```

The detail messages it emits are also helpful, describing a zero-length format string, and pointing out that C syntax does not allow general text at the point where the 'G' in "Goodnight" appears.  Both of those are pointing you to the same thing: the text "Goodnight Moon!" is intended to appear inside a string literal (which literal would serve as `printf`'s format string), but instead, an empty string (`""`) appears, with the text after.

Why? Because one quotation mark comes directly from the command executed by `make` to build the source file:

> ```
>     @echo "int main(){printf(\"`cat $F`\");}" >> hello.c
> ```

```
here -----------------------------^
```

and the other comes from file `greetings-file.txt`, which you say contains, literally,

```
"Goodnight Moon!\n"
```

A similar problem appears at the end of the greeting line, too.  I suspect that there has been some miscommunication about the preparation of these files, but perhaps it's all part of the exercise.  Anyway, one set of quotes needs to go (or the ones in the makefile could simply be unquoted).

Comment: Thanks! I removed the quotation marks and I got this error compile hello.c cc -o hello hello.c /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function _start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile-hello:27: recipe for target 'hello' failed make: *** [hello] Error 1 –

Comment: @IsaacAttuah, the error you now describe suggests that some other malformation was introduced into your source file.  The error message is insufficient to determine exactly what, but you probably will be able to tell by looking at the generated `hello.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the closing "  in the printf statement

Comment: I included it in different positions and I got similar errors